# How to access parent website css from child website using php

Tags: php, html, css

I've following PHP Folder structure:

example1.com

```
-->/
-->/assets/
-->/assets/css/style.css
-->/example2.com
-->/example2.com/{respective folders}
```

Here, example1.com and exampl2.com are two domains. How can it be possible in `HTML` or `PHP` for example2.com to access the

```
/assets/css/style.css
```

Actually I was trying to build something like SaaS in PHP i.e. one codebase, multiple domain and multiple database for domain.

Comment: You create symlink for any folder. For one folder or more.

Comment: Is there any way possible using PHP or HTACCESS? @u_mulder. Actually I was trying to build something like SaaS in PHP i.e. one codebase, multiple  domain and multiple database for domain.

Comment: Using this for what?

Answer (score 0):

For HTML:

As far as the browser is concerned, there is no relationship between the two sites at all. You can access the stylesheet like any other resource, you just need to provide an absolute URI to it.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://example1.com/css/style.css">
```

For PHP:

You are just dealing with the local file system. You can access the files by specifying their paths. The fact you are exposing some of them over HTTP is immaterial.